# Angular 2 page refresh after lgoin to system

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I just need to refresh the page after user logged in to the system? I search this in google but I could not be able to find any solutions. Please help.

```
returnUrl:String = '/admin/dashboard';
submitForm(value: any) {
    if (this.myForm.dirty && this.myForm.valid) {
        this.authenticationService.login(this.user).subscribe(
            /* happy path */ respond => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = respond;
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user.token));
                }
                this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SUCCESS', 'You have successfully logged in');
                return this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            },
            /* error path */ error => {
                this.toasterService.pop('error', this.sharedService.errorMsg, error);
            }
        );
    } else {
        this.toasterService.pop('error', this.sharedService.errorMsg, 'Invalid data submission');
    }
}
```

after navigated to admin/dashboard I want to refresh the dashboard component.

Comment: Please post the code to help you or some pseudocode

Comment: You need to inject Location and then location.reload()

Comment: thank you for the quick respond @JayakrishnanGounder. I updated the question.

Comment: @Mork Could you please explain little bit

Comment: @rdanusha: do you want to refresh the page (dashboard component) on regular basis, once you are navigated to admin/dashboard? Things would get called first time if you write it inside ngOnInit or constructor

Comment: @rdanusha sorry. Try window.location.reload(); Don't need inject any.

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I just need to refresh the dashboard page only after logged in only.

Comment: @Mork window.location.reload(); didn't work :(

Comment: @rdanusha please post the code for dashboard component and routing if possible.

Comment: You should never reload your whole page in an Angular 2 app. Either you don't have it loaded yet and it should load through `ngOnInit()`, or there are parts of your UI that you need to update, and for that you should use a service

Answer (score -1):

this may be irrelevant, but  why would you want to do that?
Howeever, the answer would be something like

```
    submitLog(){
//on login service success
    this.document.location = "";
     }
```

that would redirect you to youre index page